# Terraform - aws_lambda_permission APIGW source ARN format example stopped working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

In [aws_lambda_permission](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_permission.html), there is an example of the source ARN which is granted access to lambda functions.

The `source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.execution_arn}/*/*/*"` part had been working until early today 4/APR/2020, but suddenly stopped working.

Anyone noticed the same or if there is something wrong in the code, please suggest.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowMyDemoAPIInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "MyDemoFunction"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  # The /*/*/* part allows invocation from any stage, method and resource path
  # within API Gateway REST API.
  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.execution_arn}/*/*/*"
}
```

Not sure what has changed, if it is on AWS side or Terraform AWS provider side.

## Examples

#### Used to work

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_apigw_invoke_lambda_receive_question_alias" {
  statement_id  = "1"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.mysfit.execution_arn}/*/*/*"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = local.lambda_receive_question_function_name
  qualifier     = local.lambda_receive_question_function_alias
}
```

**Generated result**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:11111111111:function:mysfit_mysfitsReceiveQuestion:v1",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2::s8qgrp3acc/*/*/*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Works now

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_apigw_invoke_lambda_receive_question_alias" {
  statement_id  = "1"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.mysfit.id}/*/*/*"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = local.lambda_receive_question_function_name
  qualifier     = local.lambda_receive_question_function_alias
}
```

**Generated result**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:1111111111:function:mysfit_mysfitsReceiveQuestion:v1",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:1111111111:s8qgrp3aeb/*/*/*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## API GW Source ARN Format

The format works now is below, as far as I tested.

```
"arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:${AWS_REST_API_ID}/${AWS_API_DEPLOYMENT_STAGE_NAME}/${REST_API_METHOD_HTTP_VERB}/${REST_API_RESOURCE_PATH}"
```

In Terraform:

```
"arn:aws:execute-api:${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.mysfit.id}/*/${aws_api_gateway_integration.question_post.integration_http_method}${aws_api_gateway_resource.question.path}"
```

or

```
"arn:aws:execute-api:${data.aws_region.current.id}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.mysfit.id}/*/*/*"
```

Comment: Your aws_lambda_permission in work now section is not working for me. Did you try this again? Are you facing any issue?

Comment: I can confirm that changing the ARN as stated it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using this format in the *source_arn* argument:

> "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.myapi.execution_arn}/*/*"

of the *aws_lambda_permission* resource worked for me.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api-gateway-permission" {
   statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
   action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   function_name  = "${var.function_name}"
   principal = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
   source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.myapi.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

I'm using Terraform v1.2.3 on linux_amd64.

Reference: [How to Integrate AWS Lambda with Amazon API Gateway Using Terraform Code](https://blogs.perficient.com/2022/05/03/how-to-integrate-aws-lambda-with-amazon-api-gateway-using-terraform-code/)